# Extending a react native iOS project to tvOS - linked libraries

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, tvos

I’m working on a React native project for iOS and tvOS. I’ve started with the version for iOS but I would like to extend the Xcode project/workspace to also build for tvOS. React (Native) code (logic) and state management will be fairly the same for both targets. There are just some UI adjustments but that’s not going to be a big deal.

The problem I’m having now is building the app. For iOS need to link libraries that are not available (nor do I need them) on for the tvOS target. For example the: [Orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation). I’ve automatically linked this library to use for for iOS, but this is now causing the app not to build for tvOS, since orientation is not available on that platform. The library doesn’t show up in the list of linked libraries for the tvOS target, but for some reason while building the app Xcode tries to add it and then breaks the build.

Hopefully you guys can help me with this issue, I feel like I’m overlooking something.

I've made a screenshot of the error that I get while building:

[image: error]

Comment: Are you importing the `Orientation` library in any of the source files that you share between the iOS and tvOS targets? From the error messages it seems that you are importing `Orientation` in `AppDelegate.m`, which seems to cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your conditional compilation like,

```
#if TARGET_OS_IOS
  extern UIInterfaceOrientationMask ORIENTATION;
#endif
```

The above example is using Objective C code